# здравствуйте, у меня проблема с оптимизацией сайта на телефон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Я использую адаптивную вереску сайта, когда я включаю сайт на телефоне можно сдвинуть в право и получается, что сайт можно болтать в право, лево. Там пустое место, я ломаю себе голову уже 3 дня, и не могу решить эту задачу. https://bluecoc.online/chil.html - вот сайт где можно посмотреть код. мне нужно чтобы сайт был на весь экран [image: вот так выглядит проблема на телефоне]

Comment: А `margin-right: 1100px` у ссылок на мобильном убрать не желаете?)

Comment: Используйте bootstrap для адаптивной вёрстки, либо придётся с помощью `@media` прописывать каждый стиль.

Comment: Совет: Потратьте время для обучения bootstrap. Это в разы ускорит разработку.

Comment: я не особо знаю что такое bootstrap, можно пожалуйста ссылку где обучатся, а то я не нашел

Comment: @ДанилаТотсамый [сайт](https://getbootstrap.com/), документация [тык](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/)